# Moving text mode cursor not working

Tags: c++, assembly, osdev

I have been working on moving the text mode cursor in the operating system I am currently developing. I am having trouble getting it to show up at all. Here is the code that I use to update the cursor:

```
   void update_cursor()
    {
        unsigned char cursor_loc = (y_pos*Cols)+x_pos;
         // cursor LOW port to vga INDEX register
        outb(0x3D4, 0x0F);
        outb(0x3D5, (unsigned char)(cursor_loc));
        // cursor HIGH port to vga INDEX register
        outb(0x3D4, 0x0E);
        outb(0x3D5, (unsigned char)((cursor_loc>>8)));


    }
   static inline void outb(unsigned short port, unsigned char value)
   {
      asm volatile ( "outb %0, %1" : : "a"(value), "Nd"(port) );

    }
    static inline unsigned char inb(unsigned short port)
    {
       unsigned char ret;
       asm volatile ( "inb %1, %0" : "=a"(ret) : "Nd"(port) );

       return ret;
    }
```

I use gcc version 4.8.3 (GCC) to compile my main file. I am completely lost. Anyone have any suggestions as to what might be the problem with this?
If you want to see the full source it is located here: https://github.com/AnonymousUser1337/Anmu/blob/master/Kernel/kernel.cpp

**EDIT**: I am using Virtual box to run it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You select wrong VGA registers. You have to use 0x0F for low and 0x0E for high (you have 0x0A for both).

Edit: In case your cursor is disabled, this is how to enable it:

```
void enable_cursor() {
    outb(0x3D4, 0x0A);
    char curstart = inb(0x3D5) & 0x1F; // get cursor scanline start

    outb(0x3D4, 0x0A);
    outb(0x3D5, curstart | 0x20); // set enable bit
}
```

Also check [this link](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/specs/freevga/vga/crtcreg.htm) for list of register numbers and usages.

Edit2: Your cursor location variable is not wide enough to store the cursor location. `unsigned char cursor_loc` should be `unsigned short cursor_loc`.

Comment: I tried that still no luck the cursor doesent even show up I edited my code to match what you suggested

Comment: @AnonymousUser Is the cursor visible before calling update_cursor?

Comment: I thought that update cursor was supposed to make it visible and no it isn't

Comment: Still not working I enable cursor at beggining of program and then I update every time I print Nothing at all. I printed curstart and it came out as 14 if that helps

Comment: I'll try and see figure out what's wrong, But it looks like it should work.

Comment: Anyone have any idea what my problem is I just really don't know what is going on I have tried to debug it will look into it more in deapth

Comment: It looks like it was actually the way I cleared my screen before I printed everything thanks anyway :D it works now

Answer (score -1):

Your outb function has port and value in the wrong places. Instead of:

```
asm volatile ( "outb %0, %1" : : "a"(value), "Nd"(port) );
```

Try:

```
asm volatile ("outb %1, %0" : : "dN" (port), "a" (value));
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Looking at his Makefile he's using the default GCsettings for inline assembly which is AT&T syntax .With AT&T syntax it is source, destination so they are using `outb` correctly with AT&T syntax. Had they compiled with `-masm=intel` then this would have been a problem.