# text mode cursor doesn't appear in qemu vga emulator

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly, qemu, osdev

I have a problem with the function that updates cursor position in text mode
the function definition and declaration are

```
#include <sys/io.h>
signed int VGAx = 0,VGAy=0;
void setcursor()
{
        uint16_t position = VGAx+VGAy*COLS;
        outb(0x0f, 0x03d4);
        outb((position<<8)>>8,0x03d5);
        outb(0x0e,0x03d4);
        outb(position>>8,0x03d5);
}
```

and the file sys/io.h

```
static inline unsigned char inb (unsigned short int port)
{
        unsigned char value;
        asm ("inb %0, %%al":"=rm"(value):"a"(port));
        return value;
}
static inline void outb(unsigned char value, unsigned short int port)
{
        asm volatile ("outb %%al, $0"::"rm"(value), "a"(port));
}
```

before using the function the cursor sometimes was blinking underscore and sometimes didn't appear while after using the function no cursor appeared

here is the main function that runs

```
#include <vga/vga.h>
int kmain(){
        setcursor()
        setbgcolor(BLACK);
        clc();
        setforecolor(BLUE);
        terminal_write('h');
        setcursor();
        return 0;
}
```

I tried using this function

```
void enable_cursor() {
    outb(0x3D4, 0x0A);
    char curstart = inb(0x3D5) & 0x1F; // get cursor scanline start

    outb(0x3D4, 0x0A);
    outb(0x3D5, curstart | 0x20); // set enable bit
}
```

which is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321608/moving-text-mode-cursor-not-working) but I got this error 
`inline asm: operand type mismatch for 'in'`
any help is appreciated

**EDIT**
I tried to fix the wrong `inb` and `outb`:

```
static inline unsigned char inb (unsigned short int port)
{
        unsigned char value;
        asm volatile("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(value) : "Nd"(port));
        return value;
}
static inline void outb(unsigned char value, unsigned short int port)
{
        asm volatile ("outb %%al, $0"::"Nd"(value), "a"(port));
}
```

I guess this is the right definition but still no cursor appeard

**EDIT 2**
I followed the given answer and defined the `io.h` file as the following

```
static inline unsigned char inb (unsigned short int port)
{
        unsigned char value;
        asm volatile ("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(value) : "Nd"(port));
        return value;
}
static inline void outb(unsigned char value, unsigned short int port)
{
        asm volatile ("outb %0, %1"::"a"(value), "Nd"(port));
}
```

I would like to mention that I also added`enable_cursor();` to the beginning of kmain now the compile time error is fixed but no cursor appeared (which is the main problem)

**EDIT 3**
I would like to point out that a version of the whole code is availabe on [gihub](http://github.com/oddcoder/opal101) if any one want access to pieces of code that are no available in the question

Comment: The problem is that your `outb` function is messed up. `asm volatile ("outb %%al, $0"::"rm"(value), "a"(port));` this is wrong (and so is inb). `inb` and `outb` don't take arbitrary registers. Please see the [instruction reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_222.html) . The only registers that are valid are a port number being specified as an immediate 8 bit value or being passed in DX. The only output registers you can use are al/ax/eax .

Comment: Both `inb` and `outb` are are wrong. See this question for a correct `inb` function; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791997/gcc-inline-assembly-nd-constraint

Comment: still nothing changed

Comment: sorry for not mentioning this
#define COLS 80 
#define ROWS 25
yes it is set to 80

Comment: Your code always sets the cursor to the upper left corner of the screen. Where do you update VGAx and VGAy to move the cursor elsewhere, or do you intend to always put the cursor at 0,0?

Comment: the VGAx and VGAy are updated to the position of curser in any of terminal_write or clc or terminal_control functions these functions I am sure they work perfectly and are heavily debugged

Comment: actually I provided a link to where the whole (barebone operating system exists in EDIT 3)

Comment: Although not part of your problem, your code `outb((position<<8)>>8,0x03d5);` is more easily done by a bitwise `and` of `position` with `0xff`. That will set the upper bits to 0 and lower bits remain as they are. Something like `outb(position&0xff,0x03d5);

Comment: Actually I just noticed the code in your github repository for enable_cursor() doesn't match what you posted on Stackoverflow in your question. You seem to have fixed it in one place and not the other? That type of thing is making this more difficult than need be. And since I don't intend to build and test your kernel, I think I have spent enough time on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## inb and outb Function Bugs

This code for `inb` is incorrect:

```
static inline unsigned char inb (unsigned short int port)
{
        unsigned char value;
        asm ("inb %0, %%al":"=rm"(value):"a"(port));
        return value;
}
```

A few problems with it:

- It seems you have the parameters to `inb` reversed. See the [instruction set reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_139.html) for `inb`. Remember that in AT&T syntax (that you are using in your GNU Assembler code) the operands are reversed. The instruction set reference shows them in Intel format.
- The port number is either specified as an immediate 8 bit value or passed in the *DX* register. The proper constraint for specifying the `DX` register or an immediate 8 bit value for inb/outb is `Nd`. See my Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32792177/3857942) here for an explanation of the constraint `Nd`.
- The destination that the value read is returned in is either *AL/AX/EAX* so a constraint `=rm` on the output that says an available register or memory address is incorrect. It should be `=a` in your case.

Your code should be something like:

```
static inline unsigned char inb (unsigned short int port)
{
        unsigned char value;
        asm volatile ("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(value) : "Nd"(port));
        return value;
}
```

Your assembler template for `outb` is incorrect:

```
static inline void outb(unsigned char value, unsigned short int port)
{
        asm volatile ("outb %%al, $0"::"rm"(value), "a"(port));
}
```

A couple problems with it:

- The port number is either specified as an immediate 8 bit value or passed in the *DX* register. The proper constraint for specifying the `DX` register or an immediate 8 bit value for inb/outb is `Nd`. See my Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32792177/3857942) here for an explanation of the constraint `Nd`.
- The value to output on the port has to be specified in *AL/AX/EAX* so a constraint `rm` on the value that says an available register or memory address is incorrect. It should be `a` in your case. See the [instruction set reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_222.html) for `outb`

The code should probably look something like:

```
static inline void outb(unsigned char value, unsigned short int port)
{
        asm volatile ("outb %0, %1"::"a"(value), "Nd"(port));
}
```

## Enabling and Disabling the Cursor

I had to look up the VGA registers about the cursor and found this [document](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/specs/freevga/vga/crtcreg.htm#0A) on the *cursor start register* which says:

> ```
>    Cursor Start Register (Index 0Ah)
>
> -------------------------------------------------
> |  7  |  6  |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1  |  0  |
> -------------------------------------------------
> |     |     | CD  |     Cursor Scan Line Start  |
> -------------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> CD -- Cursor Disable
>
> This field controls whether or not the text-mode cursor is displayed. Values are:
>
> > 0 -- Cursor Enabled
> >
> > 1 -- Cursor Disabled
>
> Cursor Scan Line Start

An important thing is that the cursor is **disabled** when the *bit 5* is **set**. In your *github* `setcursor` function you do this:

```
outb(curstart | 0x20, 0x3D5);
```

`curstart | 0x20` **sets** *bit 5* (0x20 = 0b00100000). If you want to **clear** *bit 5* and **enable** the cursor, then you bitwise *NEGATE*(~) the bitmask and bitwise *AND* (&) that with `curstart`. It should look like this:

```
outb(curstart & ~0x20, 0x3D5);
```

## VGA Function Bugs

Once you have the cursor properly enabled it will render the cursor in the foreground color (attribute) for the particular video location it is currently over. One thing I noticed is that your `clc` routine does this:

```
vga_deref_80x24(VGAx,VGAy) = \
        vga_encode_80x24(' ',BgColor,BgColor);
```

The thing to observe is that you set the attribute for the foreground and background colors to `BgColor` . If you set the `bgcolor` to black before calling `clc` it will flash a black underline cursor on a black background rendering it invisible on any screen location. For the cursor to be visible it must be on a screen location where the foreground and background are different colors. One way to see if this works is to change the code to:

```
vga_deref_80x24(VGAx,VGAy) = \
        vga_encode_80x24(' ',BgColor,ForeColor);
```

I think it is a bug that you are clearing it with encoding `vga_encode_80x24(' ',BgColor,BgColor);` I think you mean to use `vga_encode_80x24(' ',BgColor,ForeColor);`

Now in your `kmain` function you need to set a *ForeColor* and *BgColor* before calling `clc` and they both must be different color to make the cursor visible. You have this code:

```
setbgcolor(BLACK);
clc();
setforecolor(BLUE);
```

It should now be:

```
setbgcolor(BLACK);
setforecolor(BLUE);
clc();
```

Now if the cursor is rendered anywhere on an unwritten location on the screen it will flash BLUE underline on BLACK background.

This should solve your cursor problem. However, I noticed that you also use `encode vga_encode_80x24(' ',BgColor,BgColor);` in your VGA `scrolldown` and `terminal_control` functions. I think this is a bug as well, and I think you should use `encode vga_encode_80x24(' ',BgColor,ForeColor);` instead. You do seem to set it properly in `terminal_write`.

If you want to change the color of the cursor at any location you could write a function that changes the foreground attribute under the cursor location without changing the background color. Make sure the two attributes (Foreground and background color) are different for the cursor to be visible. If you wish to hide the cursor you can set foreground and background color the same color for the screen location the cursor is currently at.

Comment: still no luck getting a cursor to appear :(

Comment: yes but still no pointer appears on the screen and the goal was to get the function to run correctly and I tried to explain the problem by showing the compile time error however the error is solved the goal is not achieved

Comment: I you could please help me finding out why didn't the cursor appear because It took me long time I am good with assembly but the problem is that it is my first time to work with ports

Comment: yes actually I typed this out almost before I read your answer

Comment: then I copied and pasted your functions as they are

Comment: thats is the last version I am using
`static inline unsigned char inb (unsigned short int port)
{
        unsigned char value;
        asm volatile ("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(value) : "Nd"(port));
        return value;
}
static inline void outb(unsigned char value, unsigned short int port)
{
        asm volatile ("outb %0, %1"::"a"(value), "Nd"(port));
}
`
sorry for bad format

Comment: I swear I fixed it in my code and I will edit the post ]

Comment: @AhmedAbdElMawgood I have amended my answer to provide you information on fixing your bug that prevented you from enabling your cursor. The code you have actually disables it (opposite of what you wanted it to do).

Comment: @AhmedAbdElMawgood : I have amended my answer with information on  how the cursor gets displayed and a series of problems you have with setting the foreground and background color that effectively hide the cursor. I have now presented a solution for that.

Comment: thank you very much I really want to thank you even my TA(s) couldn't give any help I am grateful for your precious help

Comment: This post was very helpful — thanks. (My particular problem was that when I scrolled the display, I zero'd out the last line, setting the color to black-on-black — i.e., invisible — and thus, also the cursor.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your outb code. Also be aware of order port and value parameters.

Following works for me:

```
static inline unsigned char inb (unsigned short int port)
{
    unsigned char value;
    asm volatile ("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(value) : "Nd"(port));
    return value;
}


static inline void outb (unsigned short int port, unsigned char value)
{
    asm volatile ("outb %b0,%w1": :"a" (value), "Nd" (port));
}

void update_cursor(int x, int y)
{
    uint16_t pos = y * 80 + x;
 
    outb(0x3D4, 0x0F);
    outb(0x3D5, (uint8_t) (pos & 0xFF));
    outb(0x3D4, 0x0E);
    outb(0x3D5, (uint8_t) ((pos >> 8) & 0xFF));
  }
```